# GDPR Communication Preferences Compulsory

Tags: civimail, gdpr

I am using Civirm 5.1 on Joomla and using the GDPR extension to update Communication preferences. The org has only 1 public facing group with just 1 Mailing list - and the entire purpose of the communication is to ask people if they wish to sign up. If they do not repond they will be removed from Group and if they do respond it is ONLY for the purpose of asking to receive newsletter. Therefore, we need to make the Mailing Group compulsory to sign (as opposed to optional). We do not want form used if you do not want newsletter.

see form here

https://peoples-press.com/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/gdpr/comms-prefs/update

1 tick box option to MS Newsletter - any ideas how to make compulsory in settings?

Answer (score 1):

One route is to do the following:

Modify the section

> Communication Preferences
>   We want to ensure we are only sending you information that is of interest to you, in a way you are happy to receive.

to make it clear that by signing up they are signing up to the Newsletter

then in Comms Pref settings page, untick the "Allow users to opt-in to mailing groups"

then on your MS Newsletter profile - use the Adv Settings to 'add them to group'

i think that makes it really clear what folk are signing up for
and removes the extra tickbox for the newsletter from the form

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion - it seems to work fine for me - I also changed text under Data Policy to indicate signing up to Newsletter.

Comment: It seems I spoke to soon - I created a new user with email - sent user test email - clicked sign up in email - completed remaining fields and clicked save - however, GDPR comm preferences not updated in contact and contact is NOT added to Group despite stating so in Advanced Profile.

Comment: If I do the above recomemendation but otherwise leave the Subscriptions to Groups ticked and the form works as expected and eners person into Group - If left unticked then contact will not be placed in group despite Advanced setting adding to Group.

Comment: The form is designed to be explicit consent i.e. supporters must tick the box for the group your going to add them to. We haven't tested them being automatically added to groups as its against GDPR guidelines however if you raise an issue on our extension issue queue we can take a look https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.gdpr/issues.